# CCMenu vs CCSprite position Cocos2d-x

Tags: position, cocos2d-x, ccsprite, ccmenuitem, ccmenu

I'm very confused with a weird behaviour in Cocos2d-x, when I create a CCSprite and a CCMenu with a single CCMenuItem, even thought all of them are positioned at the same location.

```
mySprite->setPosition(ccp(0,0));
myMenu->setPosition(ccp(0,0));
```

mySprite is at one place and myMenu with its myMenuItem are at another location, what is happening? and how can I fix this?

Thanks! :'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I was using setScale on CCMenu, this messes up the position of every child, you have to use setScale on each CCMenuItem instead of the CCMenu.

Answer (score 0):

In a CCMenu you are not supposed to manually change the position of the items (and their children). Only change the position of the menu itself.

Comment: Hi! I removed the line that changes the item position but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

```
Sprite->setPosition(ccp(100,100));
Menu->setPosition(ccp(100,100));
```